# Python on visual studio comment colour change?

Tags: python, visual-studio, colors, comments

I'm using Python in Visual Studio and normally when doing the comments, the comments usually turn green after putting in the hashtag (#).

But sometimes it doesn't. And I don't know how to fix it.

[image: The code]

Comment: it seems like your python language server is having some buggy behavior. I'd probably try to reinstall the lang server, and if that won't work, reinstall vscode.

Comment: Pylance v2023.12.1 in VSCode 1.85.2 highlights the error with json.loadfile() which suggests that your IDE and its extensions may be out-of-date

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio as your text and tag suggests, or Visual Studio Code (VS Code) which is a completely different application?